# Struts2 Is there a way to add metadata to action definition in struts.xml file?

Tags: java, struts2

I use the Struts2 framework to create a webapp. I have an interceptor that should have different behaviour depending on which action is invoked. For example, a login interceptor that should always allow some actions to execute, but it should block other actions if the user is not yet logged in.

The way I solve this now is by manually checking the name (and/or namespace) of the action in the interceptor, and determine my behaviour based on that. The downside of this "hardcocded" logic is that it is hard to maintain if I edit my struts.xml file, and it is also not obvious what is going on for other developers.

I would like to know if these is some way to add 'metadata' INSIDE the struts.xml file (or other file?) to "mark" certain actions as being  certain "type". For example, something like this:

Struts.xml

```
<action name="loginPage" types="login, user, viewpage" class="login.controller.LoginPage">
    <result name="success">/login/jsp/Login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

And then in my interceptor class:

```
@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation)
throws Exception
{
    Set<String> actionTypes = invocation.getInvocationContext().getTypes();

    if(actionTypes.contains("login")
    {
        doSomething();
    }
    else
    {
        doSomethingElse();
    }        

}
```

Is this possible, or is the hardcoded parsing of name(space) the only way?

Comment: You can't modify a DTD, can you?

Comment: No, there isn't, unless you either change the DTD, or create the real config file during build or deployment.

The canonical approach is to use annotations or naming conventions. Convention over configuration is a pretty common technique. As with any other framework ever the key is documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you can't do that because the DTD won't allow you.

Another good example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem):

> The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.
>
> That is, you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble,
>   you ask about Y.

What you *really* need is to define a group of actions running free, and other groups running under login control.

For this, you can manually include the Interceptor in each single action (useful when using the Convention plugin, a waste of time otherwise), or configuring the actions logically in the struts.xml.

The `<package>` is your friend here: define two (or more) packages, one running with the default settings, the other running your custom Interceptor for each action of the package:

```xml
<package name="unsecure-package" namespace="/unsecure" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="login" class="org.foo.bar.actions.LoginAction">
        ...
    </action>
    <action name="askHelp" class="org.foo.bar.actions.AskHelpAction">
        ...
    </action>    
</package>

<package name="secure-package" namespace="/secure" extends="struts-default">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="authInterceptor" 
                    class="org.foo.bar.interceptor.AuthInterceptor"/>

        <interceptor-stack name="securedStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="authInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <default-interceptor-ref name="securedStack"/>

    <action name="write" class="org.foo.bar.actions.WriteAction">
        ...
    </action>
    <action name="delete" class="org.foo.bar.actions.DeleteAction">
        ...
    </action>        
</package>
```

This way every time you or somebody else will add an Action in struts.xml, it will just need to drop it in the right package, and it will work automatically.

It's better to keep the Interceptor action-agnostic whenever possible ;)

Comment: I already have multiple packages to group actions logically (for example, everything that deals with item management is in the item package). I also have multiple interceptors, not just the login example. to go through with your plan, I would need dozens of packages like the Item_Login_NoMessage_ClearCache_StorePreferences package. How would you deal under those circumstances?

Comment: You can use inheritance... for example, the highest separation is between `logged_in` / `not_logged_in`. You won't probably need anything custom in the `not_logged_in` actions, but in the case you can configure the missing interceptors for those single actions. Then you start defining the `logged_in` package. Adding packages that extends it when there are different actions (let's say at least 3) needing the same feature, that is not needed/wanted in other packages. It would not lead to "dozens" of packages, but generally (based on the size of the webapp) to 4-5 well organized.

Comment: For example, I wouldn't use StorePreferences (assuming it is related to the MessageStore Interceptor) at Package level, it's a lot better at Action level. The Cache is 50%/50%... the NoMessage is already part of the StorePreferences... etc

Comment: Ok gotcha, I'll try some refactoring and see if stays manageable. I'll give feedback if I have concerns. thanks

Comment: I gave it a try and by carefully building a hierarchy of packages that extend each other I can indeed produce the desired result. I must note however, that some kind-of duplication occurred. Like, do I create the packages item->blue/item->red and user->blue/user->red, or do I create the packages red->item, red->user and blue->item, blue->user (an arrow denotes extends)? I'm not sure if some scheme exists to fit this kind of "matrix". In this example it's a 2x2 matrix, but imagine a bigger one!

Comment: It depends on how much blue, red, item, user actions you have, and how complex / shifted from the default their configuration is... Interceptors, results, exception mappings... This is a common problem, with different solutions according to each case. Try to keep it simple and to follow DRY at the same time, without falling in the esoteric :) the only constant usually is the login, hence my answer